Completing the square to solve this inequality
How can I apply completing the square to solve this inequality:
$p^2 \cdot (1+c^2)-2p\cdot(q+\frac{c^2} 2)+q^2 \leq 0$
Where $p, q \in [0,1]$ and $c \geq 0$.
I need to have the inequality in the form of $p \geq ...$

The inequality is $(p-q)^2 +c^2p(p-1)\leq0.$ But what are you solving for? What have you tried? Why do you want to solve this?

Your own title contains an excellent suggestion for a first step. Have you tried completing the square (with respect to $p$)? Where did you get stuck?

The general form of a quadratic expression $a x^2+b x+c$ can be written as:
$$
a\left(x^2+\frac{b}{a} x\right)+c=a\left(x+\frac{b}{2 a}\right)^2-\frac{b^2}{4 a}+c
$$
You can apply this to your quadratic inequality, where $a=1+c^2, b=-2\left(q+\frac{c^2}{2}\right)$, and $c=q^2$. You should be able to continue from this point.
